# Как работает display: table-cell в данном примере?

Tags: css

Почему, если елементам задать table-cell и ширину в 1%, они делят всю ширину родителя между собой?
И почему при уменьшении размера окна на первом елементе появляется непонятный padding, который смещает его вниз?

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__item {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
}
.nav__item:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
.nav__item-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__item-link">Link 1 222222</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__item-link">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__item-link">Link 3</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__item-link">Link 4</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__item-link">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Потому что все ячейки таблицы, принадлежащие одной строке таблицы, занимают В СУММЕ всю ширину этой строки. В данном случае - родителя.
2. Потому что происходит следующее:

   1. Содержимое ячейки (первого элемента) переносится на вторую строку.
   2. Высота первого элемента увеличивается и это заставляет увеличиваться высоту соседних ячеек.
   3. "Непонятный padding" неявно добавляет браузер для ячеек, которые получают размер больше изначально заданного.
   4. Смещение вниз происходит из-за того, что vertical-align по умолчанию = baseline и содержимое ВСЕХ ячеек выравнивается относительно друг друга по базовой линии - нижней кромке букв текста первой строки без учета выносок.

Поставьте стиль `vertical-align:middle`, например, сами увидите что к чему.

Comment: Почему они разделяют ширину родителя если задать им ширину в 1%, если убрать это свойство они занимают как inline-block?

Comment: Потому что так рендерит браузер таблицы.
если задать ВСЕМ ячейкам одинаковую ширину, то браузер попытается отрендерить так, как я сказал выше, потом расширив ячейки пропорционально контенту.
А если ширину не задавать, то да, будет как инлайн-блок, ибо приведенная конструкция - не полноценная таблица. Если сделаете нормальную таблицу, ее ячейки займут в сумме всю ширину таблицы даже если вы им ничего не зададите. А ширины ячеек будут пропорциональны контенту.